# Websocket doesn't open connection

Tags: python, websocket

I try to use websocket instead of rest api, but `on_open` event seems to be not working. I get only after a while `on_close` event, but i can't find any issue. The sctipt ends without errors.
I don't understand what is parameter `ws` in `on_open` method and where is defined. 
Below example cames from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpheJQz673s

```
import websocket
import threading
import _thread
import json

class SocketConn(websocket.WebSocketApp):
  def __init__(self, url, params=[]):
    super().__init__(url=url, on_open=self.on_open)

    self.params = params
    self.on_message = lambda ws, msg: self.message(msg)
    self.on_error = lambda ws, e: print('Error', e)
    self.on_close = lambda ws: print('Closing')

    self.run_forever()

  def on_open(self, ws,):
    print('Websocket was opened')

    def run(*args):
      tradeStr = { "method":"SUBSCRIPTION", "params":self.params }

      ws.send(json.dumps(tradeStr))

    _thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

  def message(self, msg):
    print(msg)


threading.Thread(target=SocketConn, args=('wss://wbs.mexc.com/ws',["spot@public.deals.v3.api@BTCUSDT"])).start()
```

Comment: That program terminates after starting a thread!? Why are you using a thread there to begin with?  Why are you using both `threading` and the low-level `_thread` module? How are you testing that code? You could btw. `print(repr(ws))` to find out about `ws`. Also, try to find a video tutorial on running the code in a debugger. Oh, one more note: Python uses 4 spaces indent by convention, see https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation. This makes it easier when exchanging code.

Comment: I think you need join this thread. It means you need wait this thread executed